# what's the difference between jdk7 & jdk8 in Generic?

Tags: java

```java
List<String> box = new ArrayList<>();
box.add("small");
box.addAll(new ArrayList<>());
```

in jdk7 `box.addAll(new ArrayList<>())` will not compiled, but in jdk8 is will

anyone can give me a help to understand what's the difference between jdk7 & jdk8 in Generic?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Is it JDK7 and JDK8, or JDK6 and JDK7?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri even Java6 have addAll https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)

Comment: Type inference was improved in Java 8; without these improvements, lambdas and streams would have been incredibly awkward.

Comment: @YCF_L, I was more referring to diamond operator. Maybe that could've be the issue, I thought.

Comment: if i change the code to `box.addAll(new ArrayList<String>())` in jdk7 is also well

Comment: @Guy error msg is :  `java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Object> could not cast to java.util.Collection<? extends java.lang.String>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the improved type inference [JEP101](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/101) in effect; it infers the generic type of the empty list. Specifically, this is the addition of inference in argument position.

Comment: The "diamond operator".

Comment: @OhleC you means the difference is Target-Type Inference ?

Comment: @huangbotao yes

Comment: @OhleC i was confused that jdk7 can comple `List<String> box = new ArrayList<>()` it should also can complie `box.addAll(new ArrayList<>());` to `box.addAll(new ArrayList<String>());` but why not?

Comment: Because type inference in 7 was very simple; it inferred from assignments, not from method arguments.

Answer (score 6):

The difference is that Java 8 introduced *polyexpressions*.

These are expressions whose type is left somewhat undetermined, but is determined by context of how the expression is used.

`new ArrayList<>()` is a polyexpression. On its own, it could be a list with any element type: the compiler "waits and sees" before it decides on the type.

Java 7 didn't support polyexpressions. It would consider `new ArrayList<>()` to be `new ArrayList<Object>()`, and thus incompatible with `box.addAll`.

Without polyexpressions, lambdas and streams would have been incredibly awkward.

Comment: thanks for you help! I searched for a document by keyword "polyexpressions" and it's link[](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.2)

Comment: thanks for you help! I searched for a document by keyword "polyexpressions" and it's link[](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.2)
```
When some expressions appear in certain contexts, they are considered poly expressions. The following forms of expressions may be poly expressions:

+ Parenthesized expressions (§15.8.5)

+ Class instance creation expressions (§15.9)

+ Method invocation expressions (§15.12)

...

```

I think this is not the root cause for this question, can you give me more word to understand you means?

Comment: @huangbotao `new ArrayList<>()` is a class instance creation expression, and from 15.9 "A class instance creation expression is a poly expression (§15.2) if it uses the diamond form for type arguments to the class, and it appears in an assignment context or an invocation context" (this is an invocation context).